# Tic Tac Toe Game java using only methods and 2d arrays

Tags: java

Still cannot figure out what im doing wrong. I have no idea how to get the CPU choice into the board. I did get the board to re display the updated board with the row and column the player selected. I need to have 4 methods and id like them to do exactly only this: 1) displayBoard (takes single passed parameter of 2d array representing current tic tac toe board. 2.) makeAMove (takes 2 passed parameters: Two dimensional array representing tictactoe board and player character value ('X' or 'O'). Updates array with valid row and column selected by player character. This method does NOT return anything, it simply updates the board array. 3.) hasWon (Takes 2 passed parameters, 2 dimensional array representing TicTacToe board and player character ('X' or 'O'). Return TRUE if player character has won, FALSE otherwise. 4.) boardFull (Takes single passed parameter of two dimensional array representing TicTacToe board and return TRUE if all cells are occupied, false otherewise. These area ll the methods, some of which i have done in an ineffiecient way (i know) but im trying to teach myself just the logic of it first without using any classes. Anyone that can either comment here it would greatly help as i feel stuck at this point.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TicTacToe {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        char[][] board = {{'1','2','3'}, {'4','5','6'}, {'7', '8', '9'}};
        // assign player to char value of X's only

        int play;

        char player = 'X';

        char cpu = 'O';

        int rowNumber;

        int columnNumber;

        int playerORow;
        int playerOcolumn;

        System.out.println("Welcome to tic, tac, toe!\n");

        System.out.println("Do you wish to play? 1 for yes, 2 for no ");

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        play = input.nextInt();

        if(play != 1) {
            System.out.print("Invalid input, game will now EXIT thanks for playing!");
            System.exit(0);
        } // end if

            displayBoard(board);
            System.out.println("You are limited to X's only, good luck!");
            System.out.println("Please enter row (0-3) of your move: ");
            rowNumber = input.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Please enter column (1-3); of your move: ");
            columnNumber = input.nextInt();

            System.out.println("Please enter row (0-3) for player O: ");
            playerORow = input.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Please enter column (1-3); of your move: ");
            playerOcolumn = input.nextInt();


            if(board[rowNumber][columnNumber] != 'X' && board[rowNumber][columnNumber] != 'O')  {
                board[rowNumber][columnNumber] = player;
            } // end if

            else {

            }


            makeAMove(board, player);
            hasWon(board, player);
            boardFull(board);

} // end main method

// displays only the tic tac toe board
public static void displayBoard(char[][] board) {
    // loop for each row
    System.out.println(board[0][0] + " | " + board[0][1] + " | " + board[0][2] + "\n---------");
    System.out.println(board[1][0] + " | " + board[1][1] + " | " + board[1][2] + "\n---------");
    System.out.println(board[2][0] + " | " + board[2][1] + " | " + board[2][2] + "\n");

} // end display board method

// takes board array of values and updates it with valid row and column selected by player..does not return anything
public static void makeAMove(char[][] board, char player) {
    displayBoard(board);


} // end makeAMove method


// compare each element in board to see if the char value of 'X' exists
    // if exists then then return true, else return false
public static boolean hasWon(char[][] board, char player) {

        // Check if the player has won by checking winning conditions.
        if (board[0][0] == player && board[0][1] == player && board[0][2] == player || // 1st row
            board[1][0] == player && board[1][1] == player && board[1][2] == player || // 2nd row
            board[2][0] == player && board[2][1] == player && board[2][2] == player || // 3rd row
            board[0][0] == player && board[1][0] == player && board[2][0] == player || // 1st col.
            board[0][1] == player && board[1][1] == player && board[2][1] == player || // 2nd col.
            board[0][2] == player && board[1][2] == player && board[2][2] == player || // 3rd col.
            board[0][0] == player && board[1][1] == player && board[2][2] == player || // Diagonal          \ 
            board[2][0] == player && board[1][1] == player && board[0][2] == player) //   Diagonal      /

            return true;

        else {

            return false;
        }

} // end hasWon method

public static boolean boardFull(char [][] board) {

    if (board[0][0] != '1' && board[0][1] != '2' && board[0][2] != '3' &&
        board[1][0] != '4' && board[1][1] != '5' && board[1][2] != '6' &&
        board[2][0] != '7' && board[2][1] != '8' && board[2][2] != '9')

        return true;

    else {

        return false;
    } // end else

} // end boardFull method
```

} // end class

Comment: Have you been taught about creating & working with multiple classes? This problem really does need a couple of other classes.

Comment: No not yet. We're supposed to be using only multi-dimensional arrays. Here are the directions only from the book, not from what the instructor wants though. http://www.eduk8tech.com/apcs/Multidimensional_Arrays.pdf Page 254, exercise 7.9.

Comment: So it isn't a homework is it? If you're doing this only to learn, then I could put some more suggestions.

Comment: yeah if u can thatd be great b.c ive been working on this for 4 hours straight and just not getting how to prompt over and over, validate everything, just say if player has won or lost, and print if the board is full or not..

Comment: Are you coding this for 4 hours, without thinking about the what all would you need? Ok, here comes my first suggestion. You should think about "what", before "how". Do it on paper, before you touch a computer.

Comment: Gonna print all this out now, take a break, and reassess everything step by step. Hopefully i can do this!

Comment: Sure you can do this. No issues :)

Comment: JUst posted updated code rohit..just getting super confused between all the do while and while loops i threw in there from the suggestions. Im trying to get the game to say "continue playing?" If (1) yes then loop through the game again, else, System.exit(0);

Comment: I don't see any `do-while` loop there.

Comment: wait nvm, i took that out, im trying to just get the game to run once at this point

Comment: just dont know how to randomize that CPU char 'O' and implement it in the board.

Comment: I didn't get your last comment.

Comment: just dont know how to randomize that CPU char 'O' and implement it in the board

Comment: I have the variable char declared but just not sure how im supposed to randomly assign it one of the rows or columns and then display it back on my board...

Comment: Are you playing CPU vs Player?

Comment: Yeah. The game will only let me run once then dont know why it wont prompt player to input row and column again?..

Comment: First, don't involve CPU. It will really require much more work, and much strong algorithm to analyse the board, and make the best move. Let's make it work for two players. Then think of improving it. Secondly, do you know how to read multiple inputs from a user? Have you been taught about loops? If you are writing Tic-Tac-Toe game, I would really expect you to know basic Java stuffs. If not, then please don't dig into complex problem like these. First get yourself comfortable with those.

Comment: Agh sorry didnt know what i meant to say. Im trying to simply have the user (assigned to char 'X') input the row and column they would like. Then, have the player do the same for other player (player 'O') And yeah i can read multiple inputs as well as write loops. Just have everything mixed up for some reason in this program and don't know where im going wrong..

Comment: added two more variables for player O in main.

Comment: That is why I suggested you to stop coding, and think about the problem first. Come up with some design. What all classes would you need. What method will go in which class. What all fields will be there in each class. That will make your life so much easier.

Comment: Well i posted what each method needs to do in the description above. I cant make this into a class since i have not learned that. Just trying to implement it in the way i described above using only those methods at a minimum

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48409/discussion-between-rohit-jain-and-javaaaaaa)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just have to do this:

```
board[rowNumber][columnNumber] = player;
```

Of course you would have to check beforehand that cell is not already occupied. If yes, then ask again for user input. I guess that wouldn't be that tough.

Apart from that, I would suggest you some improvements to your code:

- Rather than having two players as `char` types, use an `enum Player`, with two constants - `X` and `O`. And use a `Player[]` instead.

  ```
  enum Player {
      X, O;
  }
  ```
- No need to initialize your array with `'1', '2', ...`. Now that they will be `null` by default.
- Rather than having `board` as local variable, and passing it in all the methods, make it a field in your class.
- Currently your code is making just one move. Why? Also, you're not even using the return value of `hasWon()` and `boardFull()` method.
- You can divide the `hasWon` method into 3 methods - `hasWonHorizontal()`, `hasWonVertical()`, `hasWonDiagonal()`. This will avoid that long `if` condition in the same method. And then call these 3 methods in sequence from `hasWon()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Seems all you need to do is check to see if player/cpu has already taken that space.  If not, you should just assign 'X' or 'O' to that element in the array.

```
if(board[rowNumber][columnNumber] != 'X' && board[rowNumber][columnNumber] != 'O')
    {
        board[rowNumber][columnNumber] = player;
    }
```

You will probably want to have some kind  of loop within your main() function to continuously allow players to move as well.  The current implementation appears to only allow a player to make one move.

Comment: hmm im a total noob at the moment with all this so sorry for any stupid questions. First, im not to sure how i would go about asking player to move. Second, i placed the if statement with row and columnNumber under the System.out statement of "X will be placed in.." Also to how would i implement those return statements with the program?..assign a varaible to hold each method that says return in main? Or what? Gosh! So confused guys :/

Comment: I think you can use all of our three answers to figure out how to make it best. Use the idea of a loop I presented you, use SchwartzCode's codesnippet to check the board and place a new marker, if it's occupied ask again (this can be done with do/while or while). And for further improvements make the variables fields, improve some methods and maybe use an enum as Rohit Jain suggests. The return-values can be used to assign variables or for direct checks. Example: `boolean playerWon = hasWon(board, player);` or the direct check: `if(hasWon(board, player)) { doIt(); } `.

Answer (score 0):

First a direct answer to your question:

```
// update board array with player row number and player column number
board[rowNumber][columnNumber] = player;
```

To show the new board you can just call your `displayBoard()` method again.

You should be careful with your scanner as it doesn't validate the input. If you get a number not in [0..2] you will get an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds here, so you might want to do something like

```
do {
    System.out.println("Please enter row (0-3) of your move: ");
} while((rowNumber = input.nextInt()) < 0 || rowNumber > 2);
```

and the same for the column to prevent this. Also you can add checks for strings and so on.

Some other aspects for the game:

- Do you want to ask to continue before every move? If not, better move it to a new method and ask it once in the beginning.
- Make board, player and cpu class variables. (or see below)
- Use a loop around your game state, you already have a very nice "state"-machine by providing your functions:

.

```
// a possible loop/game might look like this:
if(askForPlaying()) {
    char currentPlayer = player;
    while(!(boardFull(board) || hasWon(board, player) || hasWon(board, cpu)) {
        displayBoard(board);
        if(currentPlayer == player) {
            makeAMove(board, currentPlayer);
        } else {
            cpuMove(board, currentPlayer);
        }
        currentPlayer==player?cpu:player;
    }
    if(hasWon(board, player)) System.out.println("You won!");
    if(hasWon(board, player)) System.out.println("You lost!");
}
```

The best way to improve your game would be to make a TicTacToe class and a Main class. The TicTacToe class would hold the board, the player, the cpu and some methods to display the board and modify it, and maybe also to switch the player and so on.

The Main class would then just create the TicTacToe instance and run a main loop (the while-loop I posted above) which modifies it accordingly. But for now just go with your approach and maybe later you might want to improve it further. Then you can come back and think about it.

Comment: Am a little confused about validating the input. Doesnt it need to say do {
    System.out.println("Please enter row (0-3) of your move: ");
} while((rowNumber = input.nextInt()) > 0 || rowNumber < 3); <---??